# AsyncStorage doesn't seems to work on my physical device

Tags: javascript, android-emulator, react-native, asyncstorage

My react-native app works perfectly fine on the emulator. But when I transferred it to the actual device, callbacks from AsyncStorage doesn't seem to work. I even tried releasing the apk. but having no luck.

I'm storing the item from a file 'Attraction.js' like this.

```
async addToRecentSearches(){
try{
  var recentSearches = JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem("@travelGeo:recentSearches"));
  var hasAMatch = recentSearches.find((el)=>{
    return el.name.toLowerCase() === this.props.navigation.state.params.attraction.name.toLowerCase();
  })

  console.log("hasAMatch", hasAMatch);

  // add the attraction to the AsyncStorage if the attraction doesnt already exist
  if(!hasAMatch){
    if(recentSearches && recentSearches.length===3){
      /***push attraction and pop one***/
      recentSearches.unshift(this.props.navigation.state.params.attraction);
      recentSearches.pop();
      AsyncStorage.setItem("@travelGeo:recentSearches", JSON.stringify(recentSearches) );

    }else if(recentSearches && recentSearches.length<3){
      /***push this attraction to the array***/
      recentSearches.unshift(this.props.navigation.state.params.attraction)

      AsyncStorage.setItem("@travelGeo:recentSearches", JSON.stringify(recentSearches) );
     }else{
      /***add this attraction to the storage***/
      let arr = [];
      arr.unshift(this.props.navigation.state.params.attraction);

      AsyncStorage.setItem("@travelGeo:recentSearches", JSON.stringify(arr));
    }
  }
}catch(e){
  console.log(e);
} }
```

and i'm calling this async function from componentDidMount

```
componentDidMount(){
 this.addToRecentSearches();
}
```

And then I'm trying to retrieve the data from a different route(Weather.js) like this.

```
async componentWillMount(){
try {
  let recentSearches = JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem("@travelGeo:recentSearches"));
  console.log(recentSearches);
  this.setState({testGet:recentSearches[0].name})
  for(var i=0;i<recentSearches.length;i++){
    if(recentSearches[i].location){
      let response = await getWeatherByLocation(recentSearches[i].location.latitude,recentSearches[i].location.longitude);

      recentSearches[i].currentWeatherData = response;
    }
  }

  console.log("recentSearchesWithWeatherData", recentSearches);
  this.setState({recentSearches:recentSearches});

} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
}
```

(I'm using async in componentWillMount() is just for testing purposes.)
And I'm using `{recentSearches:recentSearches}` state to render the data.

This code works perfectly fine in the emulator. but doesn't seem to work on the actual device. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, I'm an idiot... it was a really stupid mistake.
The error was thrown from this line

`var recentSearches = JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem("@travelGeo:recentSearches"));`

I've been trying to retrieve a value from the asyncstorage which haven't been set.

in the emulator however, when I was first writing the code, I must have set the `"@travelGeo:recentSearches"` key. So, it does work on the emulator but not on the physical device.